# {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Guid'."} System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq

This is the method in my service.

```
public async Task<InvitedUser> CheckEmail(string Email)
{
    var result = await _db.InvitedUser.SingleOrDefaultAsync(_ => _.Email == Email);
    return result;
}
```

The schema for Invited User is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Project.Core.Entities
{
    [Table("InvitedUser")]
    public class InvitedUser
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid UserAccountId { get ; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Guid ReferrerAccountId { get ; set; }    
        public string Name { get; set; }    
        public string AccessCode { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }         
    }
}
```

Now whenever I execute this above mentioned LINQ query it gives this error

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Guid'."}

I've also tried

```
var result = _db.InvitedUser.Where(i => i.Email== Email)=.FirstOrDefault()
```

Still no progess.

EF Verison: 5.0.9
C# Version: 3.1

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the `CREATE TABLE` statement from the table `InvitedUser` in your database.

Comment: Is the column `ReferrerAccountId` nullable in the table schema? If so, you may need to type the associated property as `Guid?`.  Another possibility is that either `UserAccountId` or
 `ReferrerAccountId` is typed as something other than `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` in the table schema.

Comment: @progman                                                                                                          
       CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InvitedUser](
 [UserAccountId] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
 [Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
 [AccessCode] [varchar](255) NULL,
 [Status] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [CreatedAt] [datetime] NULL,
 [ReferrerAccountId] [varchar](100) NULL,
 [Email] [char](150) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [UserAccountId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: @TN RefferrerAccountId and UserAccountID both of these are Guids. UserAccountID is not nullable, and ReferrerAccountID is nullable.

Comment: @Hamza, edit your question and add additional details. Do not use comments for create table scripts and classes definition.

Comment: @Hamza You should index the ***Email*** field to avoid performance issues. The `SingleOrDefault()` query converts into `select * where Email = @p0 take 2`. This means: result only returned if a 2nd entry is found or end of table reached - in case of no index.

Comment: In your query, can you try parsing the db returned string to a guid? Select{ UserAccountId = Guid.Parse(UserAccountId)...}

Comment: @Hamza - Since you confirmed that column is `ReferrerAccountId`, have you tried changing the `ReferrerAccountId` property data type to **`Guid?`** as previously suggested - `public Guid? ReferrerAccountId { get ; set; } `?

Comment: I tried you class and the linq query above: it works without errors. You wrote something else in API fluent configuration, in OnModelCreating? You are migrating from a previous database configuration? What provider are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ReferrerAccountId and UserAccountId field types are 'varchar' which is string. But your properties in the model has Guid type.

So
You should either save the string fields in the table as uniqeidentifier type
or
define them as string in your model(instead of Guid).

Comment: Much appreciated it worked, but how can we have Guid as a datatype in SQL create script and have the same data type in the code .?

Comment: If you create your tables with sql script by DB First, when creating table;
[UserAccountId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, line will work.
If you specify 'not null' it is correct as you define it. If you specify 'NULL' (as nullable) in the script, it will be added to your model must be this way : 
'public Guid? UserAccountId { get ; set; }'.

Comment: @Hamza, if it worked you should mark his answer as an answer, turning into a green check.